# Birds with overlapping summer and winter ranges

Tags: ornithology

My question is about bird species with overlapping summer and winter ranges, like [fieldfares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieldfare). What happens in the overlap area? Do the birds that breed there also stay there, or do they migrate to the south while their place in winter is occupied by their relatives who breed in the north?

Comment: It's possible that ranges don't actually overlap for individuals but that ranges between individuals overlap. If I live very far north and you live very far south, my southern range for me might just be your northern range.